# Show Payment options showing blank loading screen

Tags: swift, payment

I have initiated Stripe Payment Context on my view controller as below

```
customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: 
StripeClient.shared)
paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: 
customerContext!)
```

I have set the publishable keys in the app delegate
I am trying to show the payment options view controller as below

```
paymentContext?.pushPaymentOptionsViewController()
```

The problem is the presented view controller is just a blank view controller titled "Loading"
It stays loading forever

Answer (score 0):

So the customer ID was blank. Added it and it loaded properly